# Does OSGi enforce service ranking order when injecting a list

Tags: osgi, aem

When using `@Reference` in a service to inject references to multiple service (`ReferenceCardinality.MULTIPLE`) implementations, what guarantees does OSGi make on how the injected services are ordered? Are they always ordered by `service.ranking`.

Currently I do the following:

```java
@Reference(
    service = SomeInterface.class,
    cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MULTIPLE,
    policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC,
    policyOption = ReferencePolicyOption.GREEDY,
    fieldOption = FieldOption.UPDATE
)
private final List<SomeInterface> refs = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
```

(annotations are OSGi R7 anno­ta­tions)

When testing this, I always see the elements on list `refs` in descending order of their `service.ranking` but I don’t know if that’s by design or by accident and if it’s guaranteed by OSGi or not. I haven’t found a definite answer in the specifications or any blog post.

Also, does this hold when using different values for `policy`, `policyOption` or `fieldOption`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are supplying your own list (and not letting Declarative Services (DS) supply the list), DS can only call `add` and `remove` on your list object. See https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.component.html#d0e37871.

Since DS only calls your list object, your list implementation must be responsible for any desired ordering.

If you let DS supply the list, then the list will always be ordered: "sorted using the same ordering as `ServiceReference.compareTo` based upon service ranking and service id". See https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.component.html#d0e37828.

Comment: I assume this would involve making the field non-`final` and changing `fieldOption` to `REPLACE`, right?

Comment: Weirdly, when I do this the order changes so that the lowest-ranked services are ordered first in the list. I find this a bit strange. The spec clearly states that a higher ranking means the service is preferred so I would have expected the sort order to be descending, not ascending…

Comment: The DS spec states that the collection is sorted in natural order which is generally ascending. So the last item in the collection is the highest in the sort.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert did you dig for the reasoning more (e.g. on OSGi mailin lists), as it caught me by surprise as well. If "the best" service is the one with highest ranking (as suggested by BundleContext.getServiceReference()), why the list starts from the least preferred service? I know it's in the DS spec, but why?

Comment: @BJHargrave when I try to test the field using AemContext (which uses org.apache.sling.testing.mock), the order is reversed (service with the highest ranking comes first). Any chance you know why?

Comment: Apparently, it was a bug in `org.apache.sling.testing.mock`. Updating to a newer version fixed it.